# Connect to a website via HTTP in C

Tags: c, http, gcc, websocket

I have some C code that parses a file and generates another file of processed data. I now need to post these files to a website on a web server. I guess there is a way to do a HTTP POST but I have never done this in c (using GCC on Ubuntu). Does anyone know how to do this? I need a starting point as I have no clue of doing this in C. I also need to be able to authenticate with the website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: can you point me to any tutorials that get me started with libcurl. the first thing is how to download and use libcurl in a simple c code.

Answer (score 1):

I think Hank Gay's suggestion of using a library to handle the details is the best one, but if you want to "do it yourself", you need to open a socket to the web server and then send your data in the HTTP POST format which is described [here](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt). Authentication can mean a variety of different things, so you need to be more specific.

Unfortunately, all of the above three jobs involve a fair bit of complexity, so you need to break the question down into stages and come back and ask about each bit separately.